# Handle email.decoded with special character content

Tags: ruby, email

I am using the gmail gem to extract data from the content. 
When I try to call email.body.decoded, I got

```
(th=C3=B4ng tin transactio=\nn ID\nv=C3=A0 user ID s=E1=BA=BD n=E1=BA=B1m trong description n=C3=A0y)
```

from

```
(thông tin transaction ID và user ID sẽ nằm trong description này) (This is Vietnamese)
```

Is there anyway that I can handle the special characters like those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like UTF-8 being transmitted via [quoted printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding. You can use [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack) to undo the QP encoding, then force the reinterpretation into unicode:

```
str.unpack('M')[0].force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have tried unpack but it still not work.

Comment: @IanTran I tested this on the string in your question and it worked. How did it not work for you? Did you get an error message? Did you get a different result?

Comment: I tried this in the rails console. `'(th=C3=B4ng tin transactio=\nn ID\nv=C3=A0 user ID s=E1=BA=BD n=E1=BA=B1m trong description n=C3=A0y)'.unpack('M')[0].force_encoding('UTF-8')
 => "(thông tin transactio=\\nn ID\\nv=C3=A0 user ID s=E1=BA=BD n=E1=BA=B1m trong description n=C3=A0y)"`. It should be like this `(thông tin transaction ID và user ID sẽ nằm trong description này)`

Comment: @IanTran that's because you're using single quotes so the `\n` is being interpreted literally. If you print (not inspect) the original string do you see `\n` or a newline?